# Problems with user defined z3 sorts

Tags: z3, smt

I'm trying to define a new fraction sort in z3 to gain a better understanding of how z3 works. I'm using this query and define equality between two fractions:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; TEMPLATE CTOR ;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
(declare-datatypes (T1 T2) ((Pair (mk-pair (first T1) (second T2)))))

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; SORT DEFINITIONS ;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
(define-sort Fraction () (Pair Int Int))

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; FUNCTION DEFINITIONS ;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
(define-fun Fraction_Eq ((f1 Fraction) (f2 Fraction)) Bool
    (if (= (* (first f1) (second f2))
           (* (first f2) (second f1)))
        true
        false
    )
)

(declare-const x1 Fraction)
(declare-const x2 Fraction)
(declare-const x3 Fraction)

(assert (Fraction_Eq x1 (mk-pair 3 5)))
(assert (Fraction_Eq x2 (mk-pair 4 7)))
(assert (Fraction_Eq x3 (mk-pair 8 9)))

(check-sat)
(get-value (x1 x2 x3))
```

I expect that x1 will be equal to 3/5 but it isn't. Here is the answer I get:

```
sat
((x1 (mk-pair 0 0))
 (x2 (mk-pair 1304 2282))
 (x3 (mk-pair 0 0)))
```

Can anyone please help? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation

```
 n * 5 = d * 3
```

is perfectly satisfied by `n = d = 0`.

Since division by zero has no meaning in ordinary arithmetic, you should enrich your statement and require `d` being different from `0`.

Note that this does not guarantee `n, d` to be equal to `3, 5`, since there are an infinite number of solutions to that equation. The *normalised* value of `x1`, however, should correspond to `3/5`.

Here is the way to fix it:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; TEMPLATE CTOR ;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
(declare-datatypes (T1 T2) ((Pair (mk-pair (first T1) (second T2)))))

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; SORT DEFINITIONS ;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
(define-sort Fraction () (Pair Int Int))

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; FUNCTION DEFINITIONS ;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
(define-fun Fraction_Eq ((f1 Fraction) (f2 Fraction)) Bool
    (if (= (* (first f1) (second f2))
           (* (first f2) (second f1)))
        true
        false
    )
)

(define-fun Fraction_Valid ((f1 Fraction)) Bool
    (not (= 0 (second f1)))
)

(declare-const x1 Fraction)
(declare-const x2 Fraction)
(declare-const x3 Fraction)

(assert (Fraction_Valid x1))
(assert (Fraction_Valid x2))
(assert (Fraction_Valid x3))

(assert (Fraction_Eq x1 (mk-pair 3 5)))
(assert (Fraction_Eq x2 (mk-pair 4 7)))
(assert (Fraction_Eq x3 (mk-pair 8 9)))

(check-sat)
(get-value (x1 x2 x3))
```

With the result:

```
sat
((x1 (mk-pair 3 5))
 (x2 (mk-pair 4 7))
 (x3 (mk-pair (- 8) (- 9))))
```

The newly-introduced `Fraction_Valid` [SmtLibv2](http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/language.shtml) predicate should prevent any fraction, on which it is applied, from having a denominator equal to zero.